# How to use series of HTML images, acting as links, to fill in new generic HTML page?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an HTML page with 32 images - each image, when clicked, should generate the same HTML page with minor differences. All 32 images would link to this new generic HTML page and cause different content based on the image clicked.

Example: a picture of an apple leads to an HTML page, with an apple background, and information about apples.

I realize I could create 32 HTML pages and code/link directly, but I want to do this efficiently. I've tried utilizing PHP, so that each image passes a GET variable, but the variables have X and Y values that are numeric.

This is such a silly problem and I have been stumped for days on how to proceed. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**HTML sample:**

```
<input type = "image" name = "anaheim" src = "/logos/anaheim.png"></form>
```

**PHP sample:**

```
echo $_GET['anaheim_x'];
?>
```

Actual Output:
**77**

Ideal Output:
**Anaheim**

Comment: `<button name="team" value="anaheim"><img src="/logos/anaheim.png" alt="anaheim/></button>`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me now.

HTML:

```
      <form method="GET" action = "landingmain.php">
        <input type = "image" src = "/logos/anaheim.png">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "team" id = "team" value = "anaheim">
      </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo ($_GET["team"]);
?>
```

Actual Result:
Anaheim